# Why don't we use AVL tree for hash table's item storage?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, avl-tree

Recently, I was looking at the hash table which is using chaining as linked list. I came to the possibility of using the "chain" as AVL tree.
Therefore, each buckets in the hash table will have little AVL tree's root pointers. Wikipedia says hash table's worst case is O(n) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). However, if we use each bucket's "chain" as AVL tree, we can bring it down to O(ln n).

Am I missing something?
As far as I know we can replace a linked list with an AVL tree.
Wouldn't such ADT be better than single AVL tree or hash table with linked list chaining?

I searched the internet and could not find such ADT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed directly in the Wikipedia article your referenced:

> *Separate chaining with other structures*
>   Instead of a list, one can use any other data structure that supports the required operations. For example, by using a **self-balancing tree**, the theoretical worst-case time of common hash table operations (insertion, deletion, lookup) can be brought down to O(log n) rather than O(n). However, this approach is only worth the trouble and extra memory cost if long delays must be avoided at all costs (e.g., in a real-time application), or if one must guard against many entries hashed to the same slot (e.g., if one expects extremely non-uniform distributions, or in the case of web sites or other publicly accessible services, which are vulnerable to malicious key distributions in requests).

In Java, standard `HashMap` use red-black trees in buckets, if buckets size exceeds constant 8; they are linearized back to the singly-linked list if bucket becomes smaller than 6 entries; apparently real world tests showed that for smaller buckets managing them as trees loses more due to general complexity of this data structure and extra memory footprint (because tree entries should hold at least 2 references to other entries, singly-linked entries hold only one reference), than gain from theoretically better asymptotic complexity.

I would also add, that for best performance hash table should be configured so that most buckets has only one entry (i. e. they are not even lists, just sole entries), marginally less should contain two entries and only exceptional buckets occasionally should have 3 or more entries. So holding 1-3 entries in tree makes absolutely no sense, compared to simple linked list.